# AngularJS: Output HTML based on variable count

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array `slides` that contains variable `stars` inside of it. I need to grab the value for `stars` on each slide, then use that number to repeat an HTML string for each slide.

I can get the value of `stars`, but it iterates through all 6 slides, and provides their values 6 times.

I need to get all the values of `stars` only 1 time.

```
var slides = [    
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 4 
},
{ 
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 3
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 2
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 1
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 5
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 2
}
];

$scope.addStars = function(){
  i = 1;
  for (i=1; i<slides.length; i++) {
    var starsCount = slides[i].stars;   
    var starsHTML = '<a href="#">☆</a>';
    starsFinal = starsHTML.repeat(starsCount); 
    console.log(starsFinal); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like we're missing the logic that actually calls `addStars()`.  As this logic is, it shouldn't do what you are saying it is, provided it is called only once.

Comment: Why in the world are you building HTML like this?  Unless you have a really good reason behind it, this is extremely poor angularJS design.  You're much better off using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$scope.slides = [    
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 4 
},
{ 
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 3
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 2
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 1
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 5
},
{
  'text' : 'The staff was fantastic and very friendly. I would definitely recommend them to anyone. The care has been great!! - ONLINE REVIEWER',
  'stars' : 2
}
];

$scope.addStars = function(startCount) {
  return Array(startCount).fill().map(function() {
    return '<a href="#">☆</a>';
  }).join('');
}

<div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
  <div ng-bind-html="addStars(slide.stars)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code iterates through all 6 slides, and provides their values 6 times. I'm calling this function in the html as this: `ng-bind-html="addStars()"`. Maybe this is wrong?

Comment: Misread the requirements, looks like you are looking for total number of stars through all slides. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Hi @jphillips05...I must be mis-communicating...I need to iterate through the 6 slides  only 1 time.  But on each iteration, I need to get the value of stars so that it outputs with the slide being displayed.  I am using `ng-repeat` to iterate through the slides, if that helps, so maybe there are other ways of accomplishing the same goal.

Comment: @RobMyrick updated with example for template. You don't need to iterate through the list outside of ng-repeate, just reference a function on scope and tell it how many starts you need.

Comment: thank you for the update.  This worked beautifully.  And the whole AngularJS is new to me, so thank you for providing an explanation behind your code. Much appreciated.